# New Folder button in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

Windows 7 added a very handy "New Folder" button in the top toolbar of File Explorer. I can no longer see it in Windows 10. Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it like this:

1. Go to a folder (e.g. your C:\ drive)
2. Double click the "Home" ribbon in the explorer, this will expand it so you don't always have to expand it manually.
3. There is your "New Folder" Button

[image]

Comment: OMG. Can't believe I didn't see that. My Ribbon was minimized and I didn't realize that till I saw the screenshot above. Thanks for highlighting the obvious. :)

Comment: I've never known there's such a button. I've always used Ctrl+Shift+N

Answer (score 11):

By default, the "New Folder" button is shown  in the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT).
 The QAT includes a customizable drop-down menu that contains more commands.

[image]

Comment: Thx. That's handy.

Answer (score 4):

For those who prefer the keyboard, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> immediately creates a new folder in the one you're currently viewing.

Comment: That's handy. thx.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're on the Home tab of the Explorer window's ribbon.  It shows there on mine.  Make sure you actually are viewing something that can have a folder create and you have permissions. The ribbon might be collapsed.  Look under the close button in the upper right of the window for a down arrow.  If its there click it to open the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can't select more than one answer, but I'll at least vote it up.